# 2D Passing through a platform both ways while remaining stable

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

Can anyone provide me assistance  in C# with creating a platform for a 2D platformer game where I can jump up through the platform, fall down through the platform, and stand on the platform as stable land? I have looked around, and I cannot seem to find anything helpful to the cause.

Comment: Could you show what you have done so far and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

If your game is quite simple (like if your platforms are flat) you can do this very easily disabling the Collider when the player is below the platform.

If you need other objects to keep standing on the platform, you can control the collision matrix with this two methods: [IgnoreCollision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html) and [IgnoreLayerCollision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision.html).

Attach this component to every platform:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
public class ColliderActivator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;

    new Collider collider;
    Collider playerCollider;
    void Awake()
    {
        collider = GetComponent<Collider>();
        playerCollider = player.GetComponent<Collider>();
    }

    bool wasPlayerAbove = false;
    void Update()
    {
        bool isPlayerAbove = player.transform.position.y - transform.position.y >= 0;
        // This check is only to reduce calls to the physics system
        if(wasPlayerAbove != isPlayerAbove){
          wasPlayerAbove = isPlayerAbove;
          Physics.IgnoreCollision(collider, playerCollider, !isPlayerAbove);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the stability to remain there the entire time. If I disabled the collider, wouldn't that just let anything that's on top pf the platform to fall through it?

Comment: I edited my answer: IgnoreCollision only disables collisions between two specific colliders.